# Terminal shell: How to use echo instead of a text file as command-line arguments

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command-line-arguments, home-automation

I have a command line utility which needs a text file (to format the output) as argument. I only need the pure value and no formatting, so I'd like to have a one-line script to get the value.

The text file `template.file` only contains:

```
$1
```

Here's an example of my utility:

```
vclient -h 10.0.0.131:3002 -t template.file -g getTempKist
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
vclient -h 10.0.0.131:3002 -t $(echo '\$1') -g getTempKist
```

Does anyone know how to use the result of an `echo` (or maybe an alternative) instead of an external text file?

I hope someone can help.

Markus

Comment: You can propably use stdin for the input: `echo '$1' | vclient -h 10.0.0.131:3002 -t - -g getTempKist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try two things:

First, you can probably use stdin for the input like this:

```
echo '$1' | vclient -h 10.0.0.131:3002 -t - -g getTempKist
```

Some tools support the special value `-` for filename arguments where `-` stands for stdin. However this depends on the implementation of the command.

Second thing you can use if your shell (like `bash` or `zsh`) supports this is to use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
vclient -h 10.0.0.131:3002 -t <(echo '$1') -g getTempKist
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this but the tool just hangs. So this probably isn't implemented in the tool itself.

Comment: Yeah looks like it isn't. Then you can use the second approach.

Comment: Your OS/filesystem may have `/dev/stdin` available to use in place of `-` as the argument to `-t`.

Comment: @chepner Nice! If you know that the OS is Linux for example but you can't rely on a shell that will support process substitution - then using `/dev/stdin` looks like the most portable approach for use in shell scripts.

Comment: I'm using it like this now wrapped in a script file so I can call it with a parameter and reuse it: `/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/vclient -h 10.0.0.131:3002 -t <(echo '\$R1')` -c $1"

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use `echo` as a way to simply avoid creating a temporary file, then you might prefer to try seeing if you can paste directly to `stdin`. Many tools support this:

```
$ cat foo.json 
[1,2,3]

$ python -m json.tool foo.json 
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]

$ python -m json.tool /dev/stdin
[1,2,3]  <-- Paste this into the terminal then press Ctrl-D
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```

Thus, for the tool in the OP:

```
$ vclient -h 10.0.0.131:3002 -t /dev/stdin -g getTempKist
\$1  <-- Paste this into the terminal then press Ctrl-D
```

Answer (score 0):

using a command surrounded with `` (sorry, code formatting gives me trouble with these chars) first evaluates the result of the command, so surrounding your `echo` with ` may work.

Comment: Note that `` and the `$()` operator are doing the same thing: [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)

Comment: Also check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code .. Hope it helps :)